# Unable to run Grafana server on local system

Tags: grafana

I have to create a plugin for Grafana. For that i cloned the code from Github and followed [this](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v6.1/project/building_from_source/). I have managed to build the grafana but having issue in running the server. I am getting the error

```
Grafana-server Init Failed: Could not find config defaults, make sure homepath command line parameter is set or working directory is homepath
```

I did find this issue at [issue](https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-home-path-on-windows/430). I have copied the "sample.ini" and re-named it to "custom.ini" and used the following commands in the bin folder made after building the grafana

```
.\grafana-server.exe --config D:\Go-UpdatedWorkSpace\grafana\conf\custom.ini

.\grafana-server.exe D:\Go-UpdatedWorkSpace\grafana\conf\custom.ini

.\grafana-server.exe -config D:\Go-UpdatedWorkSpace\grafana\conf\custom.ini

.\grafana-server.exe -config "D:\Go-UpdatedWorkSpace\grafana\conf\custom.ini"

.\grafana-server.exe --config "D:\Go-UpdatedWorkSpace\grafana\conf\custom.ini"

.\grafana-server.exe "D:\Go-UpdatedWorkSpace\grafana\conf\custom.ini"
```

But non of them worked. I am still getting the error

```
Grafana-server Init Failed: Could not find config defaults, make sure homepath command line parameter is set or working directory is homepath
```

What am i doing wrong ? I am new to Grafana development, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue. I ran the Grafana locally by using following command

```
 ./grafana-server.exe -config "D:\Go-UpdatedWorkSpace\grafana\conf\defaults.ini" -homepath "D:\Go-UpdatedWorkSpace\grafana".
```

I executed this command on the "bin" folder created after building the grafana with GoLang. (There is also a bin folder inside the homepath directory, i think we can use any of then "bin" folder). Issue was that i was not providing "homepath" in the command. "homepath" is the directory where grafana code is cloned.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone looking for Mac, the below works. I tried with grafana version 8.x . For default install, No need to give -config as -homepath should take care. this could run from any location.

```
/grafana-install-path/bin/grafana-server -homepath /grafana-install-path web
```